# Problem with XSLT scripting in C# error "Cannot find a 2-argument function named {urn:my-scripts}Expressions()"

Tags: c#, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to use some C# functions in an XSLT validation form, but it started to show some errors and I haven't been able to figure out why.

I use an XSLT that works just fine like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
              xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
              xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" 
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
              xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
              xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
              xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
              exclude-result-prefixes="xalan gemfunc regexp date func" 
              version="1.0">
```

but when I put the code that integrates `msxsl:script` that I found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-stylesheet-scripting-using-msxsl-script it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
              xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
              xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" 
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"              
              xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
              xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
              xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
              exclude-result-prefixes="xalan gemfunc regexp date func" 

              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"      
              xmlns:user="http://www.tempuri.org/User"
              version="1.0">
```

and it returns the following error:

> Cannot find a 2-argument function named {http://www.tempuri.org/User}Expressions()

This is the c# code that I'm using

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix="user" language="CSharp">
    <![CDATA[
        public bool Expressions(string data, string pattern) {return  Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern); }

        public int issueDate_Days(string data, string type){
          var fechaEmision=Convert.ToDateTime(data);
          var fecha=DateTime.Now;
          int dif=0;

          if(type=="seven")
            dif=Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((fecha - fechaEmision).TotalDays));
          else
            dif =Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((fechaEmision - fecha).TotalDays));
          return  dif;
        }

        public int invoicePeriod(string stardDate, string endDate){
          var inicio=Convert.ToDateTime(stardDate);
          var fin=Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);
          var dif=(fin<inicio)?1:0;
          return  dif;
        }

        public int issueDate_Valid(string data){
          DateTime temp;
          int res =1;
          if(DateTime.TryParse(data, out temp))
          res=0;
          return res;
        }   
    ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Comment: Can you update your question and post the relevant section of the XSLT that is attempting to invoke the `user:Expressions()` function, and the `msxsl:script` element defining that function?

Comment: Are you actually using a Microsoft processor? Your stylesheet has a bunch of namespace declarations that suggests otherwise.

Comment: Also show us the relevant C# code so that we see which API or library you use.

Comment: Yes, i'm using  a Microsoft processor, is there something else please tell me, again thanks for the help.